# Should I check if a substring exists before trying to replace it?

Tags: python, string

In python3, is it worth checking if a substring exists before attempting to replace it? I'm checking about 40,000 strings and only expect to find substring1 in about 1% of them. Does it take longer to check and skip or to try and fail to replace?

```py
if substring1 in string:
    string = string.replace(substring1, substring2)
```

or just

```py
string = string.replace(substring1, substring2)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: No there's no need to check, it won't replace anything until it finds pattern

Comment: The first one will search twice, so will be slower. The second is good for debugging.

Comment: Use the second version.

Comment: Ask yourself, "What particular problem does the `if` check solve? How would this code behave differently if I didn't have it here?"

Comment: How often do you expect the check to fail? The first is faster if the substring isn't present; the second is faster if it is. The overall runtime then is a function of the failure rate.

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question SO is intended for, because it's really about programming style and we try to avoid subjective matters of opinion (hence my vote to close). But I also provided an answer and upvoted because this is exactly the sort of thing I would like still-learning programmers (i.e. basically everyone :) ) to be encouraged to think about.

Answer (score 2):

`Simple is better than complex`. Doing the replacement necessitates checking anyway, so no reason to write it out yourself. `Special cases aren't special enough`; you don't need any special handling to replace zero instances of the substring - it works the same as replacing any other number of instances.

Don't check.

Comment: Production code could have different approach to performance.

Answer (score 2):

Both options you have there have the same results. However in terms of performance, the second one is better than the first.

The first one will make you go through the string twice, once to check and once to replace. So it will always go through the string once, possibly twice.

The second one, will always go through the string only once to try and replace.

For the `replace` function, if the first argument (`substring1`) isn’t found in the string, nothing will happen. So the second one is perfectly safe to use.

Always remember that simpler is better.

Comment: It depends on the expected workload. `str.replace` is several times slower than `str.__contains__`, so if the substring is rarely found, you'll save time overall by checking instead of blindly trying to replace it.

Comment: On my machine, `'foo'.replace('bar', 'baz')` takes a fraction of a second for a million iterations - it's hard to imagine an application where this kind of optimization is a serious improvement. But yes, `'bar' in 'foo'` is about 4x as fast, so there's at least conceivably a scenario where it helps.

Comment: I agree with these comments, but KISS (keep it simple stupid) checking every time can make code a lot more difficult to read (especially if part of a larger process). These micro improvements (checking with the if first) aren’t worth it for a _typical_ use case.